# Converting .svg into .ttf on a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, svg, mobile, truetype

I am planning to create a **flutter** app which will take a drawing from the user and make a custom font out of it, and then after taking every letter 1 by 1,I will convert them to `.svg`, then I want to convert it into a `.ttf` file so that they can use it anywhere. 
Does anyone have any ideas on how will I convert the svg into a font file in the backend?